# How to integrate text in HTML/CSS without offset

Tags: html, css, mapping, offset

Could someone please tell me how to integrate text in HTML/CSS in a way that the first letter of a word is mapped in the next line **without offset**?

### **Examples**

**Correct way**

[image]

Comment: There are hundreds of ways, you can use table, flexbox, ....

Comment: don't know what you mean by correct way or wrong way

Comment: @Mindless: You see the letters marked in red? In the "correct" way they  align exactly under each other without any offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:[https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/Yorkford/y80o6h95/)

```
ul li  {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

ul li span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

new edit: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yorkford/y80o6h95/6/)

Comment: This looks good. However it is in a list style - any workaround to remove the list?

Comment: how do you need it?

Comment: see the new link i added

Answer (score 0):

you can also use pseudo selector
p::first-letter{ Style goes here// }

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<span>` tag for first letter in paragraph. Then style it:
`Float: left, width:100%;` and automatically you will achieve what u want.